# Create multiple custom Event Labels in Google Tag Manager

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I need to Capture 2 Event Labels in Google analytics (Label1 and Label2). When I set them in Google Tag Manager as Label1, Label2 the event gets triggered as a single Event label. I have also tried with other delimiters (, : |). In Google Analytics the Event Label is always capture as a single label. Is there any other option where I can map multiple custom Event Label for a Google Tag.

Answer (score 1):

In Google Analytics a single event can only have one label, you cannot assign more than one label to a particular event. You might want to use some string value as a delimiter, like `label2|label3|labelN` and then use regex/filter in your report to address specific cases.